# MovieClip Undefined?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make a program where I can press a button to make a timer animation start. However whenever I add a try to add a MovieCLip to the stage it always says: Undefined... Why. Someone help me :(. How am I supposed to write code and execute a movieclip?

Here is my code:

```
var mc_hero:MovieClip = new hero_mc;
addChild(hero_mc);



var rectangle:Shape = new Shape; 
rectangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
rectangle.graphics.drawRect(100, 100, 25,25); 
addChild(rectangle);

var circle:Shape = new Shape;
circle.graphics.beginFill(0x99ff00);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(90, 90, 25);
addChild(circle);


var moveleftTimer: Timer = new Timer(2000,10);
moveleftTimer.start();
moveleftTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,moveleft);

function moveleft(event:TimerEvent):void 
{

}
```

Comment: you'll need to provide us with more details on what's going wrong (e.g. full error messages, etc), and what you expect to happen to get an answer on this. I suspect this same problem has already been asked somewhere else though, so make sure you've searched through stackoverflow to see if the problem's already answered

Comment: Also have a look at how to make a [mcve]

Comment: @XxX-EliteKnight420XxX Just change `addChild(hero_mc);` to `addChild(mc_hero);` because the instance's name is **`mc_hero`** and not `hero_mc` which is the class's one ...

Comment: @akmozo doesn't he also need to add open and close parentheses?

Comment: @NealDavis You can omit parentheses if there is no params ...

Comment: I finished my own question just recently.